# Using variables only assigned in if statements

Tags: c#, variables

I am using C# with VS2013 and .Net 4.5.2.

I create a variable, assign it a value if a certain other variable is a boolean set to true. Using the same variable later, to see if I should process anything involving that variable.

```
FileInfo newFile;
ExcelPackage assetTemplate;
ExcelWorksheet assetWorkbook;

if (load.assetDelivery) // Bool in another class
{
   newFile = new FileInfo(load.assetDeliveryTemplate);
   assetTemplate = new ExcelPackage(newFile);
   assetWorkbook = assetTemplate.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
}

// In this function later on, assetWorkbook and assetTemplate are causing errors
// Error    1   Use of unassigned local variable 'assetWorkbook'    
if (load.assetDelivery)
{
   assetWorkbook.Cells.AutoFitColumns();
   destination = load.exportFileDestination + load.assetDeliveryName +              DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".xlsx";
   assetTemplate.SaveAs(new FileInfo(destination));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign `null` to your variables:

```
ExcelPackage assetTemplate = null;
ExcelWorksheet assetWorkbook = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

Compiler is complaining because there is no way for it to know that control flow will enter the check *(true part)* and your fields/variables will be **definitely assigned**. Hence the error.

You can fix that by either assigning those fields default values,

```
ExcelPackage assetTemplate = default(ExcelPackage);
ExcelWorksheet assetWorkbook = default(ExcelWorksheet);
```

or by specifying an else part:

```
if (load.assetDelivery) // Bool in another class
{
   newFile = new FileInfo(load.assetDeliveryTemplate);
   assetTemplate = new ExcelPackage(newFile);
   assetWorkbook = assetTemplate.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
}
else
{
    ExcelPackage assetTemplate = default(ExcelPackage);
    ExcelWorksheet assetWorkbook = default(ExcelWorksheet);
}
```

See: [5.3 Definite assignment - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691172(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize it with `default` value.

```
ExcelWorksheet assetWorkbook = default(ExcelWorksheet);
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you must guarantee that you initialize a local variable prior to using it. In this scenario, `assetWorkbook` will never be assigned a value if your first `if` fails, which means the compiler can't guarantee that it was ever initialized prior to use.

If you give them an initial value, even `null`, then your code will compile - just remember that if the value is `null`, then you're subject to a `NullReferenceException` if it never gets a real value, so make sure you either do a null check first, or are 100% sure you gave it a value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use defaults (c.f. the other answers), but this looks like an example of some missing functional composition. If you had a function that looked something like

```
public void CreateSheet(string exportDestination, string assetName) 
{
    FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(load.assetDeliveryTemplate);
    ExcelPackage assetTemplate = new ExcelPackage(newFile);
    ExcelWorksheet assetWorkbook = assetTemplate.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

    assetWorkbook.Cells.AutoFitColumns();
    destination = exportDestination + assetName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".xlsx";
    assetTemplate.SaveAs(new FileInfo(destination));

}
```

It would always be safe.